# Python conditional statement for range of numbers isn't working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000989

Using ArcGIS desktop 10.7. The field `Shape_area_Hect` is `float` and the field `Core_patch` is `string`. Error for following syntax:

```
def Reclass(Shape_area_Hect):
  if (Shape_area_Hect >= 12150):
    return "Core"
  elif (Shape_area_Hect >= 486 and Shape_area_Hect < 12150):
    return "Patch" 
  elif (Shape_area_Hect < 486):
    return “Less than patch”

Core_patch = Reclass(!Shape_area_Hect!)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have null values in your Shape_area_Hect field?

Comment: No, when I sort the field I only have float values.

Comment: Are you mixing spaces with tabs when indenting your code? Copy your code into  notepad++ and turn on show al characters to verify.

Comment: I don't think so. I am using spaces to indent

Comment: Please always present errors and code as formatted text rather than pictures.

Comment: Ha! Good old notepad++, look at the quotes around your returned text compared to lines 5 and 3... :)

Comment: yeah as Hornbydd hints at , line 7 has smart quotes, those cause invalid python syntax. replace them with " or '.

Comment: Yeah, that was it, thank you!